A problem about Rust generic when implementing a threapool
I'm working on a Rust project where I'm implementing a thread pool that can dynamically accept tasks with different return types. Below is the code I've written so far:
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

type Task<R> = Box<dyn FnOnce() -> R + Send + 'static>;

struct ThreadPool<R> {
    workers: Vec<Worker<R>>,
    sender: mpsc::Sender<Task<R>>,
}

struct Worker<R> {
    id: usize,
    thread: Option<thread::JoinHandle<()>>,
}

impl<R> Worker<R> {
    fn new(id: usize, receiver: Arc<Mutex<mpsc::Receiver<Task<R>>>>) -> Worker<R> {
        let thread = thread::spawn(move || loop {
            let task = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv().unwrap();
            task();
        });

        Worker {
            id,
            thread: Some(thread),
        }
    }
}

impl<R> ThreadPool<R> {
    fn new(size: usize) -> ThreadPool<R> {
        assert!(size > 0);

        let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::channel();
        let receiver = Arc::new(Mutex::new(receiver));

        let mut workers = Vec::with_capacity(size);

        for id in 0..size {
            workers.push(Worker::new(id, Arc::clone(&receiver)));
        }

        ThreadPool { workers, sender }
    }

    fn execute<F>(&self, f: F)
    where
        F: FnOnce() -> R + Send + 'static,
    {
        let task = Box::new(f);
        self.sender.send(task).unwrap();
    }
}

The problem arises in the Worker struct's implementation:
impl<R> Worker<R> {
    fn new(id: usize, receiver: Arc<Mutex<mpsc::Receiver<Task<R>>>>) -> Worker<R> {
        let thread = thread::spawn(move || loop {
            let task = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv().unwrap();
            task();
        });

        Worker {
            id,
            thread: Some(thread),
        }
    }
}

Here, I'm passing a receiver to initialize a Worker, and this requires the generic parameter R. However, this causes issues because I want my thread pool to dynamically handle tasks with different return types.
How can I modify this code so that my thread pool can accept and execute tasks with varying return types without running into issues with the generic parameter? Should I consider using trait objects or some other pattern to achieve this flexibility?

Unless you are actually using the return values for something, there is no need to have different return types. Just set all of them to (). If you need them, please specify how you need to use them.

The way to get a value back out in a situation like this would be to use a oneshot channel that is specific to that task. In execute you could for example create a oneshot channel and capture the sender in a new closure (which would also capture f) and submit that as a task. Box::new(move || { let _ = sender.send(f()); })

The only description of your problem is a repetition of your goal, prefixed by "this causes issues". You might want to update your question and state what those issues are... Looking at your code, you are probably getting an error to due R in Worker<R> being unused. But your JoinHandle<()> specifically only covers () (that is, tasks returning nothing); change () to R. Then, in Worker::new(), you probably want to remove the semicolon from task(); so that the R (instead of ()) returned by the Task is returned by thread.join(). As of now, you're throwing away the R
